# How can I hide notification, when user select option from my PreferenceActivity(SettingActivity)

Tags: android, notifications, android-preferences, preferences, android-push-notification

I am using Preferences concept for my SettingActivity and I have an SwitchPreference toggle button for notification on/off, but enable to write code for off notification, when user toggle to off notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do that also by getting the **getDefaultSharedPreferences** where your preferences are stored by your user settings and if you are using the **FCM** then here is how you can do that.

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     //here decide by getting the value of your preference manager
     SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

     if (preferences.getBoolean("your_switch", true)){
          // Your switch is on
          displayNotification();
     } else {
          // Your switch is off
          return;
     }

  }

 }
```

Comment: thank for your code this solve my problem. but how can i stop custom notification like generated from android code(App) side.

Comment: this is same either you use SharedPreferences from services or from the activity you can access them, check if the flag is enabled or disabled and decide what action needs to be taken according to business logic.

Comment: is this logic work! if i send notification from FCM(Firebase Clouding Messaging), in notification payload format. because if we send data from FCM, in notification payload format. then it is not required to call onMessageReceived() method if app in background mode.

Comment: this onMessageReceived is common for all notification and data payloads you can check it with.
remoteMessage.getData() for data and
remoteMessage.getNotification() for notifications.

Comment: I agreed with you on that, but my ask is if I send message from FCM in notification payload. at that time we cant guaranteed either FirebaseMessagingService class will call or not if our app is closed. why because notification payload does't required FirebaseMessagingService class called

Comment: yeah, u r right , it depends if our app is in foreground or background.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn on or off notification settings programmatically in android. Instead if you are using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) you can write logic in "FirebaseMessagingService()" class not to generate any notification. But this works only if your app is in foreground state. If your app is in background state or is not running, then the notification sent by the Firebase will be shown in the notification tray.

Refer to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) for more information on receiving notification using FCM in android.

Comment: @sanjeev have you saw daily hunt app or way2online. those app are providing notification off/on if we put off, then notification nerver show. either in foreground or background mode.

Comment: @MohdQasim If you go to Settings -> Installed apps -> Daily Hunt -> Notification, you can see that the notification is still on.

Comment: yeah i observe that thing,notification is on only if we off from app

Comment: your answer last sentence is confusing me to accept your answer... even I close my app(Daily Hunt) which is now in background(close from recent apps), that time also i will not get any notification.

Comment: Are you asking about the link or the background handling?

Comment: about background handling

Comment: If your app is in background the onMessageReceived() in FirebaseMessagingService class will not be called, and the notification is generated directly.

Comment: yes Agreed,but how (daily hunt) people are stoping those notification. is these peoples are sending notification in data payload format from FCM

Comment: @MohdQasim : When user turns the toggle on or off, with the help of an api you can store the notification status as on or off. And when sending notification they can use this data to identify which users have turned off notifications.